# how to Database Design for product that have more price

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I have product that have more attribute (for example color,size,material) that each attribute have value (for example color have 4 value or material have 1 value only) ,then each value of attribute of product have one price(for example product with white color  have one price and product with red color have one price).

So I want design database in Laravel 5.5 and I am confiuse in this.

Comment: We are meant to resolve isolated issues.  Ideally, we like to fix your broken coding attempt.  Show us what research you have done and what code you have managed to produce so far.

Comment: Hi. Please: See [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Give a [mcve] for what code you can write. Ask a specific question about where you are stuck. Find & follow an academic textbook on information modeling & database design. Dozens (in pdf) are online free. So is a DB course at stanford.edu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement EAV concept

EAV : Entity Attribute Value

you need to define database like:

```
products (id, title, description) e.g. t-shirt
entities (id, title) e.g. color, size
values (id, entity_id, value) e.g. yellow, red, medium, large
entityvalues_to_products(id, product_id, entity_id, value_id) e.g. t-shirt have yellow color and could be size of large
```

Also add price attribute in`entityvalues_to_products` and add `jquery` to onchange size or color value, it will add/minus price than the basic product.

like

- basic product : $40
- select color yellow : $43 ($3 added)
- select size large : $46 ($3 added again)

Comment: thank you for your answer.if one product don't have attribute that have different price and only have attributes that have one price ,so what do i save this product.because in this subject entityvalues_to_products table not use.
for example i have mobile that have color,resolution,height,type of cpu and more attribute that this mobile have only one price.
so i have products that some product have diffrent price with based on self attributes and some product have attributes that have one price only and do not have based on self attribute

Comment: Agreed. So basically every product have basic price which will be shown on by default. If that product contains some attribute based price change ten it will be updated otherwise no 0 update in price.

Comment: ok , i am agree this idea too,but do you think this idea is good solution for this subject

Comment: Well, yes same idea implemented in Magento in 2008 and still they are using. Also, many other e-commerce application using same EAV model.

Comment: and should add price in product table..it is true?

Comment: Yes you can go with adding base price in products table. if you got that accept answer and upvote. :) further, you can email me at ping@naveedramzan.com

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution could be to use [Pivot Tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) to store the price on the pivot/relationship between the product and the attribute itself (such as the colour)